# Retrieving OID values for label relations in Apache-age graph using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I'm currently working on an Apache-age graph and need to retrieve the OID values for the label relations in the graph. I'm using Postgres to manage my database and have tried querying the ag_labels schema, but it doesn't seem to contain the OID values for the label relations.

Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r' AND relname LIKE 'ag_labels_%';
```

This query returns the relname values for all label relations in my graph, but not the OID values.

I've also tried querying the pg_catalog.pg_class table directly, but this doesn't seem to return the OID values for the label relations either.

I'm wondering if there's another table or schema I should be looking at to retrieve the OID values for label relations in Apache-age. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is a single query you can run to see all the oids of the existing labels. The labels are stored in the `ag.label` table but that doesn't hold information about the `OID`. What you could try is first querying for all the labels with

`SELECT * FROM ag_label;`

and then run

`SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r';`

and in the returned rows find the names and oids of the labels you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the query:

```
SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r';
```

It will return oids as well like this:

```
postgres=# SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r';
  oid  |         relname         
-------+-------------------------
  2619 | pg_statistic
  1247 | pg_type
 27575 | _ag_label_vertex
 27585 | _ag_label_edge
 35178 | ag_graph
 35190 | ag_label
  3118 | pg_foreign_table
 35771 | _ag_label_vertex
  1260 | pg_authid
 35791 | Person
 35781 | _ag_label_edge
 35800 | RELTYPE
  3429 | pg_statistic_ext_data
  1418 | pg_user_mapping
  6100 | pg_subscription
```

The other condition "relname LIKE 'ag_labels_%'" might be the reason you are not getting the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for the command

```
SELECT oid, relation FROM ag_label;
```

It returns the OIDs of all the labels in your database, something like this:

```
  oid   |           relation
--------+------------------------------
 803774 | test_graph._ag_label_vertex
 803787 | test_graph._ag_label_edge
 803799 | test_graph."Person"
 803811 | test_graph."MARRIED_TO"
 803823 | test_graph."PARENT_OF"
 803835 | test_graph."BROTHER_OF"
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. open the configuration file oof apache-age
2. Secondly find the track-oid and turn it on. And to add it you can do this:

> autovacuum = on

> ```
> track_oid = on
> ```

3. Now save that fine and restart the server to apply changes.

After doing all the above steps , you can now use this query for the retrieval.

```
SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_catalog.pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r' AND relname LIKE 'ag_labels_%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query to retrieve id's of all the edges and vertices of a specific graph and label.

```
SELECT * FROM test."Node";
       id        |      properties                                                                                                                                  
             
-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------

 844424930131971 | {name: 'A'}
 844424930131972 | {name: 'B'}
 844424930131973 | {name: 'C'}
(3 rows)
```

"test" is graph name and "Node" is label name. Replace it with you own data.